# Android - grid item - drag and drop - want to remove item highlight

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-gridview

I want to display circular images in grid and also a feature to drag and drop the images to reposition the icons. Also I want to add circular images dynamically. So I used grid view and drag and drop framework in android (along with onItemLongClick event listener). Everything works fine. I just dont want the highlight of an item during onItemLongClick. It highlights an item creating a rectangular shadow (This is not the shadow builder as part of the drag and drop framework) behind the circular image. Is it possible to remove that highlight?

Below is the Grid item layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.steth.CircleImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/userImg"
    />
```

Below is the GridView xml.

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your GridView:

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```